# How do I make it so everyone has a separate account when they login

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a login system for a revision app. However, I was wondering if there was a way where everyone can have separate accounts.

```
Private Sub Btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnlogin.Click
    Dim sqlstring As String
    sqlstring = "select * FROM login where username = '" & txtusername.Text & "'"
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstring, connection)
    dt.Clear()
    dataadapter.Fill(dt)
    connection.Close()

    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("no such user")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If dt.Rows(0)(2) = Txtpassword.Text Then
        Flashcard.Show()
    Else
        Txtpassword.Text = ""
        txtusername.Text = ""
        MsgBox("Invalid username and password combination")
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Register.Show()
End Sub
```

That's the code I have if a user already has an account.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Register

    Dim pro As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New oledbconnection


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pro = "provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=flashcard login.accdb"
        connstring = pro
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
        command = " insert into login ([username],[password]) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("username", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("password", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        MsgBox("You have successfully signed up!")
        Form1.Show()
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myconnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

That's the code if the user presses the register button (does not have an account).

This code works where the user can succesfully login or register, but the problem is that everyone will have the same windows form. So, I was wondering if there was a way to make each windows form unique to each user?

Comment: If everyone is running the program on their own individual computer, then they will not be sharing the same instance of the form.

Comment: Please note that it is bad to concatenate values into an SQL query (e.g. `& TextBox1.Text &`): it makes it easy to break the database, even by accident. Use SQL parameters to pass the values in the query. You've used SQL parameters in the `Button1_Click` method; the same should be done in the `Btnlogin_Click` method.

Comment: If you have any concerns about the security of the logins, please see [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Sorry, your question here makes zero sense.  Are you perhaps meaning something along the lines of displaying only DATA relevant to the authenticated user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare and initialize a variable on the same line. The only information you need is if the `userName` and `password` exist in the database. Don't pull down data your don't need. You can get this with `Count`.

Always declare and dispose the connection and command it the method where they are used. Both of these objects need to be disposed so that their unmanaged resources can be released. `Using... End Using` blocks handle this.

**Always** use parameters to avoid sql injection. In `OleDb` the order that the parameters appear in the sql string must match the order that they are added to the parameters collection.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`

```
Private ConStr As String = "provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=flashcard login.accdb"   '"Your connection string"

Private Sub Btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnlogin.Click
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim sqlstring = "select Count(*) FROM login where [username] = @UserName ANd [password] = @password;"
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.Text
        connection.Open()
        rowCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If rowCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox("no such user")
    Else
        Flashcard.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Same ideas for the insert. A text box's `Text` property is always a `String` so you don't have to convert it.
You are not doing the parameters correctly. You are not using these parameters because the don't appear in the `CommandText`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Command = " insert into login ([username],[password]) values (@UserName, @Password);"
    Try
        Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Command, myconnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            myconnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    MsgBox("You have successfully signed up!")
    Form1.Show()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
End Sub
```

Finally, and very important. You should **never** store passwords as plain text. Look into salting and encrypting.